# react-native-snackbar expo alternatives recommendations

Tags: react-native, expo

Does any know of an alternative to react-native-snackbar that will work in expo?  Or something within expo that will provide similar functionality? thanks!

Comment: You can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snackbar-component` with Expo :)

Comment: @HristoEftimov Is `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snackbar` not working with Expo?

Comment: @5ervant no, it doesn't, and clearly warns about that: "Note that because this is a native module, Expo does not support it"

Answer (score 0):

You can use snackbar from react native paper that support expo as well ..more details [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@gouri/snackbar)

Comment: Do you need to download the whole library just to use a snackbar?